# Is taskflow suitable for building parallel pipelines?

Tags: c++, multithreading, api

I've been looking into [taskflow](https://github.com/taskflow/taskflow) for a user friendly API to build parallel C++ programs. Despite having great features, I cannot find an example of constructing a parallel pipeline using this framework.

For dissambiguation, the book [Parallel and Distributed Programming Using C++](https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=169479&seqNum=5) defines the **pipeline thead model** as:

> An assembly-line approach to processing a stream of input in stages. Each stage is a thread that performs work on a unit of input. When the unit of input has been through all the stages, then the processing of the input has been completed.

Is this possible with taskflow? If yes how, if not is there an alternative?

Comment: As far as I know TBB would be the proper library for pipelines: https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/tbb-documentation/top/intel-threading-building-blocks-developer-guide/parallelizing-complex-loops/working-on-the-assembly-line-pipeline.html

Comment: As an alternative you can use any multi-threading library with task queues. For examle widly used boost::asio with `strand`. `strand` guarantees sequential executions of tasks (callables) posted to io_context (which is OS thread or pool of OS threads).

Comment: The approach with boost::asio may look like this. Each assembly line stage has its own `strand` or even its `own io_context`. Each stage posts tasks to futher stage via `io_context::post` method and by wrapping a task with `strand` object which should belong to the futher stage of assembly.

Comment: I realize the op may have found what they are looking for - but for others coming across this question, Taskflow has support for pipelines (serial and parallel).  Have a look at https://taskflow.github.io/taskflow/TaskParallelPipeline.html for further details.